# how can I remove objects by attribute within a Linked List?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

How could I remove an object inside a Linkedlist. I have a class account with studentId and studentName. I enter the objects inside the list, but when I try to remove I do not know how to do it. Because every time you remove an element from the middle of the list it gets organized, meaning the indexes change. So how can I get the studentId attribute and remove the object inside the linkedList.

Sample:

```
LinkedList: Account{studentId = 1, studentName = nome1} = index = 0 , 
LinkedList: Account{studentId = 2, studentName = nome2} = index = 1 , 
LinkedList: Account{studentId = 3, studentName = nome3} = index = 2.
```

what I would like was for the user to insert the studentId that he wants to delete and I can do a code that searches and deletes that object.

```
public Account{
    private int studentID;
    private String StudentName;
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    int accountNumber;

    LinkedList<Account> linkedAccount = new LinkedList<>();
    Account obj1;

    System.out.println("Type the acc number: ");
    accountNumber = in.nextInt();
    obj1 = linkedAccount.remove(accountNumber);
    System.out.println("The " + obj1 + " has been deleted");
}
```

Every time I delete an object from the middle it changes the index of the linkedList. Rearranging. So i do not know how to do it can you help me?

Comment: What do you mean by **rearranging**? List cannot contain holes. If you have the following list: `index1 -> object1, index2 -> object2, index3 -> object3` and then you delete `object2` then your new list will look like this: `index1 -> object1, index2 -> object3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you're using `accountNumber` as the index which is incorrect, instead loop over the list and find the index of the object and then remove:

```
for (int i = 0; i < linkedAccount.size(); i++) {
     if (linkedAccount.get(i).getStudentID() == accountNumber) {
         obj1 = linkedAccount.remove(i);
         break;
     }
}
```

Further, why are you using a `LinkedList` instead of an `ArrayList`? the latter is almost always favourable.

Comment: Hi @Aomine.  Thank you for reply me and for helping me.  I know ArrayList is easier to work with in this case. But, I'm doing it that way because I'm going to have to use a Queue in another part of the program. That was the data structure teacher you asked for.

Comment: @DViga Right, I see. since you're being given instructions by your tutor then It would be wise to keep following that. good luck!

Comment: Hello @Aomine.  Dp you know Queue?

Answer (score 2):

1. If you don't need to keep a reference to the object you remove, you can just

   ```
   linkedAccount.removeIf(acc -> acc.getStudentID() == accountNumber);
   ```
2. If you want to keep a reference to the element you remove you can

   ```
   for (Account acc : linkedAccount) {
       if (acc.getStudentID() == accountNumber) {
           obj1 = acc;
           linkedAccount.remove(acc);
           break;
       }
   }

   // OR

   for (int i = 0; i < linkedAccount.size(); i++) {
       if (linkedAccount.get(i).getStudentID() == accountNumber) {
           obj1 = linkedAccount.remove(i);
           break;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Notice that in most case and basiclly an `ArrayList` is sufficient [When to use LinkedList over ArrayList in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist-in-java)

Comment: Hi @azro. Thank you for reply me. What is acc in: linkedAccount.removeIf(acc -> acc.getStudentID() == accountNumber);  and removeIf ?  sorry I did not understand.  Can you explain me?

Comment: @DViga it's  the name of a local variable that represent the current element checked by the method, you need to have "some element called acc" that'll have the good ID

Comment: Hello @azro. And removeIf?  The program did not recognize. I think I'm not understanding. Can you explain me? I'm interested in understanding this code.

Comment: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.7 (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)...  @azro -  return this message.

Comment: @DViga you can only use lambdas as of JDK8, seems like you're running on JDK7 which is why it will not work.

Comment: @azro it's worth noting that `removeIf` is not _short-circuiting_ and will remove _all_ matching items instead of just the first. if the studentId is unique (which I assume it's) then only `removeIf` will suffice in terms of removing the item but again not short-circuiting.... i.e. even after the item is removed it will traverse the entire list.

Comment: Oh. Sorry @Aomine, I did not know. I'm using this version, because that's what the teacher told us to use. This is old, but it's the one he uses at university.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option is to search the account in the list by the studentID and then remove it.

```
public Account{
    private int studentID;
    private String StudentName;

    public int getStudentID() {
       return this.studentID;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){

   int accountNumber;

   LinkedList<Account> linkedAccount = new LinkedList<>();
   Account obj1;

   System.out.println("Type the acc number: ");
   accountNumber = in.nextInt();
   for (int i = 0; i < linkedAccount.size(); i++) {
      if (accountNumber == linkedAccount.get(i).getStudentID()) {
         System.out.println("The student " + linkedAccount.get(i).getStudentID() + " has been deleted");
         linkedAccount.remove(i);
         break; // This is to exit for loop, but if you want to delete every instance in the list with this ID you can skip this break
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi @L. Ribó.  This helped me a lot.  Thank you.

Comment: @DViga That was my intention! You're welcome partner.